# (JavaScript) Find same value in different arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping, lookup, reduce

I am making a courses card component in the React app. I have two arrays with the data to fill these cards.

THE COURSES ARRAY OF OBJECTS:

```
const courses = [
    {
        id: 'de5aaa59-90f5-4dbc-b8a9-aaf205c551ba',
        title: 'JavaScript',
        description: `Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and
    typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum
    has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the
    1500s, when an unknown
    printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
    specimen book. It has survived
    not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially u
    nchanged.`,
        creationDate: '8/3/2021',
        duration: 160,
        authors: [
            '27cc3006-e93a-4748-8ca8-73d06aa93b6d',
            'f762978b-61eb-4096-812b-ebde22838167',
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 'b5630fdd-7bf7-4d39-b75a-2b5906fd0916',
        title: 'Angular',
        description: `Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and
    typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum
    has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the
    1500s, when an unknown
    printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
    specimen book.`,
        creationDate: '10/11/2020',
        duration: 210,
        authors: [
            'df32994e-b23d-497c-9e4d-84e4dc02882f',
            '095a1817-d45b-4ed7-9cf7-b2417bcbf748',
        ],
    },
];
```

THE AUTHORS ARRAY OF OBJECTS:

```
const authors = [
    {
        id: '27cc3006-e93a-4748-8ca8-73d06aa93b6d',
        name: 'Vasiliy Dobkin',
    },
    {
        id: 'f762978b-61eb-4096-812b-ebde22838167',
        name: 'Nicolas Kim',
    },
    {
        id: 'df32994e-b23d-497c-9e4d-84e4dc02882f',
        name: 'Anna Sidorenko',
    },
    {
        id: '095a1817-d45b-4ed7-9cf7-b2417bcbf748',
        name: 'Valentina Larina',
    },
];
```

MY TRIES TO MATCH AND "DE-HASH" THE AUTHORS:

```
const COURSE = props.value;
    // AUTHOR = authors.find((el) => el.id === COURSE.authors[0]);
    // const filteredArray = array1.filter(value => array2.includes(value));
    // arrA.filter(x => arrB.includes(x));
    const authorsDeHash = (authorsHashed, authors) => {
        // const myarr = [];
        for (let i of authorsHashed) {
            // console.log(authorsHashed);
            console.log(authors.find((el) => el.id === authorsHashed[i]));
            // myarr.push(authors.find((el) => el.id === authorsHashed[i]));
        }
    };
    authorsDeHash(COURSE.authors, authors);
```

UPD: since I'm already passing a ONE single course from the parent component, I don't need to search for the value in entire "courses" array. So basically I have just to find authors real names for a one course.

Comment: for...of iterates over the values, so you don't need authorsHashed[i] because i already contains that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach is as follows ...

- create an author id based [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instance by passing an accordingly [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)ped `authors` array.
- `map` the `courses` array course items each into a new item where each course item's id based `authors` array gets mapped into an author name based array by looking up the latter from the before created `authorsMap` by an author's id.

```js
const courses = [{
  id: 'de5aaa59-90f5-4dbc-b8a9-aaf205c551ba',
  title: 'JavaScript',
  description: `Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text`,
  creationDate: '8/3/2021',
  duration: 160,
  authors: [
    '27cc3006-e93a-4748-8ca8-73d06aa93b6d',
    'f762978b-61eb-4096-812b-ebde22838167',
  ],
}, {
  id: 'b5630fdd-7bf7-4d39-b75a-2b5906fd0916',
  title: 'Angular',
  description: `Lorem Ipsumchas been the industry's standard dummy tex`,
  creationDate: '10/11/2020',
  duration: 210,
  authors: [
    'df32994e-b23d-497c-9e4d-84e4dc02882f',
    '095a1817-d45b-4ed7-9cf7-b2417bcbf748',
  ],
}];

const authors = [{
  id: '27cc3006-e93a-4748-8ca8-73d06aa93b6d',
  name: 'Vasiliy Dobkin',
}, {
  id: 'f762978b-61eb-4096-812b-ebde22838167',
  name: 'Nicolas Kim',
}, {
  id: 'df32994e-b23d-497c-9e4d-84e4dc02882f',
  name: 'Anna Sidorenko',
}, {
  id: '095a1817-d45b-4ed7-9cf7-b2417bcbf748',
  name: 'Valentina Larina',
}];

// create an author id based map.
const authorsMap =
  new Map(authors.map(({ id, name }) => [id, name]));

// map each course item and for each course item's
// `authors` array map each author's id into the related
//  author name by looking it up from the `authorsMap`.
console.log(
  courses
    .map(({ authors, ...courseRest }) => ({
      ...courseRest,
      authors: authors.map(authorId =>
        authorsMap.get(authorId)
      ),
    }))
);
console.log(
  'the non mutated original `courses` array ...',
  courses,
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const authorsMap = authors.reduce((acc, author) => ({ ...acc, [author.id]: author.name }), {}); // it faster to find a value in a Map than searching in Array

const coursesWithAuthors = courses
.map(course => ({ ...course, authors: course.authors.map(id => authorsMap[id]) }));
```

Answer (score -1):

I used a `for` loop and the `Array.prototype.find()` function. Please see snippet below.

```js
const courses = [
    {
        id: 'de5aaa59-90f5-4dbc-b8a9-aaf205c551ba',
        title: 'JavaScript',
        description: `Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and
    typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum
    has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the
    1500s, when an unknown
    printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
    specimen book. It has survived
    not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially u
    nchanged.`,
        creationDate: '8/3/2021',
        duration: 160,
        authors: [
            '27cc3006-e93a-4748-8ca8-73d06aa93b6d',
            'f762978b-61eb-4096-812b-ebde22838167',
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 'b5630fdd-7bf7-4d39-b75a-2b5906fd0916',
        title: 'Angular',
        description: `Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and
    typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum
    has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the
    1500s, when an unknown
    printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
    specimen book.`,
        creationDate: '10/11/2020',
        duration: 210,
        authors: [
            'df32994e-b23d-497c-9e4d-84e4dc02882f',
            '095a1817-d45b-4ed7-9cf7-b2417bcbf748',
        ],
    },
];
const authors = [
    {
        id: '27cc3006-e93a-4748-8ca8-73d06aa93b6d',
        name: 'Vasiliy Dobkin',
    },
    {
        id: 'f762978b-61eb-4096-812b-ebde22838167',
        name: 'Nicolas Kim',
    },
    {
        id: 'df32994e-b23d-497c-9e4d-84e4dc02882f',
        name: 'Anna Sidorenko',
    },
    {
        id: '095a1817-d45b-4ed7-9cf7-b2417bcbf748',
        name: 'Valentina Larina',
    },
];
const COURSE = courses[0]
    const authorsDeHash = (authorsHashed, authors) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < authorsHashed.length; i++) {
          let author = authors.find(e => e.id === authorsHashed[i]);
          console.log(author.name)
        }
    };
    authorsDeHash(COURSE.authors, authors);
```

Answer (score -1):

So simply I've done it that way. The main problem was in the loop, lol. Instead of (let i of j) I used (let i in j).

```
const authorsDeHash = (authorsHashed, authorsOrigin) => {
        const arr = [];
        for (let i in authorsHashed)
            arr.push(authorsOrigin.find((el) => el.id === authorsHashed[i]).name);
        return arr;
    };
    const authorsArray = authorsDeHash(course.authors, authors);

    const printAuthors = (arr) => {
        const obj = { title: '', authors: '' };
        if (arr.length === 1) {
            obj.title = 'Author:';
            obj.authors = arr[0];
        } else {
            obj.title = 'Authors:';
            obj.authors = `${arr.join(', ')}`;
        }
        return obj;
    };
    const authorsObj = printAuthors(authorsArray);
```

Thanks for the answers :)